# Variance of Integral of a real white Gaussian Noise Process

Tags: noise, gaussian, random-process, integration, white-noise

[image: Integral of a Real white gaussian noise]

In this question, is the answer not equal to infinity ? Answer is mentioned as 6. But my doubt is cant we think of it like a linear combination of many independent random variables each having infinite variance, so the resulting random variable also has infinite variance. This was a question asked in GATE  exam conducted in India for Electronics and Communication stream

Comment: But is it not an integration in time domain ?

Comment: But is it not a time domain integration  from t=5 to t =7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $W(t)$ is assumed to be zero-mean, also the RV $Y$ is zero-mean. Hence, the variance of $Y$ is given by

$$\begin{align}\sigma_Y^2&=E\left\{Y^2\right\}\\&=E\left\{\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}W(t_1)\phi(t_1)dt_1\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}W(t_2)\phi(t_2)dt_2\right\}\\&=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\phi(t_1)\phi(t_2)E\big\{W(t_1)W(t_2)\big\}dt_1dt_2\tag{1}\end{align}$$

where $E\big\{W(t_1)W(t_2)\big\}$ is the auto-correlation function $R_W(t_2-t_1)$ of $W(t)$. Now you just have to figure out the expression for $R_W(\tau)$ and solve the integral $(1)$.

Comment: Isnt this integral also evaluates to infinity, because E[ W(t1) W(t2) ] is non zero only for t1 = t2 and E[W^2 (t) ] evaluates infinity , and the remaining is energy of phi (t)

Comment: @Sreejith: No, you get a Dirac delta impulse inside the integral and you can use the sifting property to solve the integral.

Comment: Its delta ( t1 - t2 ) and is zero except for t1 = t2, when t1 = t2 we get integral of delta (0). phi^2(t) ,which is different from  integral of delta ( t ) phi ^2 ( t ). how do we apply sifting property for integral of delta (0) . phi^2 ( t)

Comment: @Sreejith: You don't get an integral over $\delta(0)$, because $\delta(0)$ is meaningless. I guess you have to review the sifting property: $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\phi(t_2)\delta(t_2-t_1)dt_2=\ldots$.

Comment: Thank you very much, I got it now

Comment: @MattL. Sorry, I'm confused about the notation. In order to apply $<>$ to Y, Y needs to be a function of something, but it seems to me that the way it's defined eliminates the 
 dependency on time and hence Y is just a single number.

Comment: @Hilmar: You're right, $Y$ is just a single (random) number. I just squared it and computed the expectation of that squared number. There is no inner product of two functions involved.